# Setting the path of an ISAPI dll file creation

Tags: web-services, delphi, iis, dll, isapi

I am working on a project where I use an ISAPI dll file/web service to generate a file. I previously used a hardcoded location as to where to store the file, which worked great, I am now trying to swap it with a location stored within a specified text file.

The problem I am having is that it seems to be appending the current path of the IIS worker process 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv' to the start of the location information I store inside my text file. I am not sure if this is down to my code or an IIS 7 server setting? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Many Thanks.

Comment: Do you use an absolute or relative path to store your file?

Comment: Where do you expect the file to be stored? What's the path you use to store it?

Comment: The file location can change, at the moment I am trying to put it in a test folder on my e drive, i.e. 'e:\testfolder\', but the location is being prefixed with the C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv.

Comment: please, show the relevant code.

Comment: Well I hope it isn't total nonsense!

Comment: It's not clear what the question is. Some code would help.

Comment: @user don't like like nonsense, but your question still lacks some code to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use SetDllDirectory in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686203%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

After calling SetDllDirectory, the standard DLL search path is:

1. The directory from which the application loaded.
2. The directory specified by the lpPathName parameter.
3. The system directory. Use the GetSystemDirectory function to get the
   path of this directory.The name of this directory is System32.
4. The 16-bit system directory. There is no function that obtains the
   path of this directory, but it is searched. The name of this directory is System.
5. The Windows directory. Use the GetWindowsDirectory function to get the path of this directory.
6. The directories that are listed in the PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer, but may put you in the right direction. Working on the http://xxm.sf.net/ project, I've found you can [set the current directory](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.SysUtils.SetCurrentDir) (for the process) from within the ISAPI dll. It appears that inetinfo.exe/dllhost.exe/w3wp.exe (or any other process IIS uses to call your ISAPI from) doesn't mind and keeps operating normally.